# How to restrict user to type till 29 digits and take two decimals in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want user to type till 29 digits in UITextfield and take two decimals, So the total length of uitextfield should be 32.

Thanks

Comment: In `textfiled delegate` method `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` you can restrict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use textField delegate method to restrict input values, its called whenever the textfield text is updated/changed.

> func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn
>   range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    let newString = NSString(string: textField.text!).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

    if newString.characters.count > 32 { //restrict input upto 32 characters
        return false
    } else {

        let characterset = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789.") //0-9 digit and . is allowed

        if newString.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterset.inverted) == nil {

            let fullNumberArray = newString.components(separatedBy: ".") //Convert string into array
           if fullNumberArray.count > 2 { // more than 2 . exist
                return false
            }
           else if fullNumberArray.count == 2 { // Fractional part exist
                if fullNumberArray[0].characters.count <= 29 &&  fullNumberArray[1].characters.count <= 2 {
                    return true
                } }else {
                        // Only No decimal point exist , numeric digits only entered so far
                        if fullNumberArray[0].characters.count <= 29 {
                            return true
                            }
            }

        }

    }

    return false
}
```

**Note**
Above code allows to enter maximum 29 numeric digits and maximum 2 fractional digits.User can type numbers without decimals .If you have a restriction of only allow 32 character and there is minimum and maximum 29 digit without fraction range then some conditions will be reduced.

Answer (score 0):

```
if  let text1 = textField1.text,
    let text2 = textField2.text,
    text1.characters.count <= 29 &&
    text1.characters.count + text2.characters.count <= 32 {
}
```

this should do the job

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
>     replacementString:(NSString *)string

delegate of `UITextField` whenever user press any character on keyboard. Then in delegate you can check how many characters user has pressed and If user pressed character length is 32 then you can verify other the enter text contain 32 digits or 2 decimal or not.
Further you can make your own different logic.

Answer (score 0):

In the textField delegate method, restrict the number of input characters. The example below restricts the number of characters to 32. Note that you should make sure the input string count is more than 0 to allow deleting input characters.

```
extension TableViewCell: UITextFieldDelegate {
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    
    if string.count > 0 {
        return (textField.text?.count ?? 0) < 32
    }
    
    return true
}
```